# TracError: foo.git does not appear to be a Git repository

Tags: git, trac

Registered a new Git repositoy via web interface at Trac, but it can't sync.

Issuing the suggested `trac-admin` command for resyncing says that the repository does not appear to be a Git repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the repository path has an space at the end of it. This was causing the problem for me.

For example, the repository path was `"C:/foo/bar.git"` and I've accidentaly typed it with a space at the end: `"C:/foo/bar.git "`. So Trac couldn't retrieve the git repository.

Removed the space and it worked fine.

Comment: We have an open ticket for this issue and it will be fixed in an upcoming release: [#11371](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11371).